# limit of square root of function and example of group

Tags: calculus, group-theory, limits

can somebody help in getting the value of

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 9}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}- 3}{\sqrt{x}-3}$, if $f(9) = 9$ and $f(9) = 4$.  
   Though the problem seems to be very simple, when I tried the question I was unable to find the value of $f(9+h)$ from the given information.
2. Give an example of a group of order greater than 2 in which each element is inverse of its own.
   I know that a group of three elements is necessarily abelian, and in proving this we use a case when each element is inverse of its own, but I am unable to get an exact example.
   Can somebody please enlighten me with one example or some hint?

Comment: square root is only at function f(x) and x

Comment: Sheetal, these questions are not related to each other and therefore should be made separate. There should be one post about the limit, and then a different post about the group theory question.

Comment: You have two totally unrelated questions here, one in calculus and the other in group theory. That's not how the Q&A format works. Your second condition should surely say $f\,\color{Red}{'}(9)=4$ by the way.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, "square root is only at function f(x) and x"

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I've edited now, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @ZevChonoles, thanks for the rectification.

Comment: i know but the first question was not being taken alone as such by the format.

Comment: It's strange that whatever format these questions came to you in, they were together like this. It's also strange you apparently think that should dictate how *you* format your questions on the site!

Comment: @anon its not my dictation... and it's also too strenge that instead helping me with solutions you seems to be more interested in looking at format and commenting.

Comment: How to post your two questions was up to you, not up to someone else. It's not strange at all I'm more interested in looking at your choice and commenting on it: the two questions themselves are run-of-the-mill, something I don't need to help with because help for them will be widespread, whereas posting a calculus and a group theory question in one is something that sticks out! (However, I did provide a little help: I mentioned that you should have $f'(9)=4$, not $f(9)=4$. That little mistake could have potentially hurt your chances of receiving help a tad.)

Comment: hey i got answer for the two ... thanks all

Answer (score 2):

By the derivative definition we have

$$\lim_{x\to 9}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}- 3}{\sqrt{x}-3}=\lim_{x\to 9}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}- \sqrt{f(9)}}{x-9}}{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt 9}{x-9}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)'\Big|_{x=9}}{(\sqrt x)'\Big|_{x=9}}=\frac{f'(9)\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{f(9)}}=f'(9)=4$$

Comment: where have you found $f'(9)?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It was given (incorrectly) by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

For the group you can think about [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) with the following presentation:
 $$V_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^2=1\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$$

Comment: hey thanks I got Z2*Z2. can you tell all elements of V4 by the way!

Comment: Nice, @Babak. +1

Comment: @SheetalSarin: Follow the link and then look at the [Cayley table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) of $V_4$

Answer (score 0):

Direct usage of L'Hospital rule would give you a defined term and on substitution you will have 4 as answer.